# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. After Import

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After importing my code from Eclipse to Android Studio and fixing the build.gradle minor problemes as usual, I tried to compile the code into my External emulator, but i had these errors.

> package com.google.admob.integration.libs does not exist
>
> package com.google.constantes does not exist
>
> cannot find symbol variable LibConstante
>
> cannot find symbol variable Admob

and in Java files i got:

> cannot resolve symbol 'constants'
>
> cannot resolve symbol 'LibConstante'
>
> cannot resolve symbol 'Admob'

Edit:

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'}
```

PS: I'm new to Android Studio .

Comment: Do you include admob dependency in build.gradle?

Comment: How i should do that ?

Comment: Do you use admob?

Comment: Yes i do it in my app .

Comment: So how do you include the admob? Is it a jar?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just added the dependancies